# Where should I install a large app if they recommend not using /opt?

Tags: software-installation

[Pentaho documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0F0/0G0/030):

> If you are using Linux, we do not recommend that you install the
>   software in the /opt/ directory. The complicated permissions
>   requirements and general isolation from the rest of the system can
>   cause unintended issues to arise if the software is installed there.

Oddly, the default folder for the install wizard is `/opt/Pentaho`.

Should I ignore the warning and install to /opt or not?

Comment: To be honest, I find the description quite vague. They don't mention *what* issues "complicated permissions requirements and general isolation" might cause, nor why. Nor do they suggest other directories than the, as you say, default `/opt`  directory.

Comment: Well, I went ahead and started the install using /opt/pentaho.  I posted on their forums asking the same question. If they don't provide compelling reason and I don't run into any issues, I guess I'll just pretend I never noticed the warning.

Comment: If they recommend not installing it on `/opt` because of the size, it might be in case you have a separate partition for that directory for multiple Linux on the same disk. In that case it can be better to put it in your home as it's supposed to be larger, but the directory of install shouldn't really change anything..